# .NET Core 2.2 Web API - Field Validation Decorators not firing on manual assignment

Tags: validation, model

I have a model class (simplified below):

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonRequired]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[ -'A-Za-z]{2,30}$", ErrorMessage ="The field firstName must be between 2 and 30 characters and contain alpha characters only.")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstname")]
    public String Firstname { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[ -'A-Za-z]{2,26}$", ErrorMessage = "The field middleName must be between 2 and 26 characters and contain alpha characters only.")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "middlename")]
    public string Middlename { get; set; }
}
```

The decorators work when I fire the API from Postman - and the error is returned.

I am currently creating UNIT Tests and want to check the validation but manual assignment through code allows it through e.g.

```
Person testPerson = new Person();
testPerson.middlename = "Bob123";
```

and therefore the Unit Test passes (or fails depending on your point of view!)

Is there a simple way through Unit Tests to check for this type of validation?

Answer (score 0):

OK. So the below does what I need:

```
Person testPerson = new Person();
testPerson.middlename = "Bob123";

        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var context = new ValidationContext(testPerson);
        Validator.TryValidateObject(testPerson, context, validationResults, true);
```

And looking at the "validationResults" reveals the particular error message of the field that fails - e.g. middlename.